# Get client IP in javascript/angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get client IP in my angular app. 
I'm using this code:

```
$http.get("http://l2.io/ip.js").then(function(response) {       
    $scope.ip = response.data;  
});
```

But it make

> Error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://l2.io/ip.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9001' is therefore not allowed access.

How to add headers?

Comment: Error says everything you need to know.

Comment: You cannot use ajax here. The site [http://l2.io](http://l2.io) mentioned another way to use their data in your javascript. Did you even read it once ?

Comment: You are making a crossdomain request to a js file. What is your intention/motive? to get the client's IP address or Server's IP address.

Comment: Get client ip address for tracking users login .

Comment: You can use jsonp for that. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a service provider that provides CORS headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *) for javascript based requests:

https://freegeoip.com

Test the following XMLHTTP request for a sample:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp.responseText)
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Or in case of jQuery Use:

```
$.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: @sahal kindly upvote / approve the answer if it helps you out